# Reference installed module from exe and ignore packaged version

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-2.x, pymssql

I have inherited a python application. The application has an exe compiled using `PyInstaller` contains lots of dependencies. It also has .py scripts in the same folder as the exe.

The application uses `Pymssql` to talk to an `mssql` database. I need to modify one of the external scripts so that it talks to an `azure` database.

It seemed like a simple task. I modified the connection parameters, installed `OpenSSL` and `FreeTDS`. However, when I try to connect I always get the error: "server required encryption but support is not compiled in".

I believe that it is using the `pymssql` module that is in the exe, not the newly installed version. I can see that the version of FreeTDS is older.

**How do I get the app to ignore the old version and to use the system installed one?** I have tried something like:  `from sys import pymssql as pymssql2` but I just get error cannot import name `pymssql`.

I don't have the code that was used to create the exe and is not sure if I have all the dependencies that it uses. So I would like to avoid creating a new exe if possible.

This is my first time using python so I apologize if I have the terminology all wrong!

Answer (score 0):

You're in a tough spot.  Once the program is compiled to an exe, there is very little flexibility. the only way import statements could be changed after compilation would be if the source specifically allowed for that.

try [this](https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/Pyinstxtractor) to decompile.  You may lose all of the comments that were in the source if it works.